# Vue.js parent <-> child updating value, routing view

Tags: javascript, vue.js, routes, parent-child

I'm having issue regarding updating parent prop in child view. In my case Contestant is parent, EditContestant should be child. Contestant.vue should store (yeah, probably answer is right here - store as in Vuex) user info and EditContestant should only render edit view, allow for edit user info action and save it via own method or parent method. I've included routing so you should get what I'm talking about.

Structure is:

```
Contestant.vue
|-EditContestant.Vue
```

Contestant.vue:

```
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            return {
                contestant: {
                    id: this.$route.params.id,
                    gender: '',
                    firstname: '',
                    lastname: '',
                },
            }
        },
    methods: {
            fetchContestant(id) {
        //some api call here                            
              vm.updatePropContestant(res.data);
        // ...
            },
            updatePropContestant(newData) {
                if (!this.contestant || this.contestant.length === 0) {
                    this.contestant = {};
                }
                this.contestant.firstname = newData.firstname;
                this.contestant.lastname = newData.lastname;
                this.contestant.id = newData.id;
                this.contestant.gender = newData.gender;
                // this.$forceUpdate();
            },
        },
        }
</script>
<template>
    <div>
        <router-view :contestant="contestant"  @interface="contestant = $event"></router-view>
    </div>
</template>
```

EditContestant.vue

```
<script>
    export default {
        data() {
            console.log('data');
            return {
                editContestant: {
                    id: '',
                    'firstname': '',
                    'lastname': '',
                    'gender': 0
                },
                edit: false
            }
        },
        props: ['contestant'],
        created: function () {
// tried also to fetchContestant if parent beforeCreate method with same result, so tried moving it here :(
            this.$parent.fetchContestant(this.$route.params.id);
        }
    }
</script>

<template>
<div class="col">
<input id="firstname" v-model="this.$parent.contestant.firstname" type="text" class="form-control"                                placeholder="First name" 
<!-- this doesn't help either v-on:input="updateParentValue($event.target.value)" --> >
                </div>
</template>
```

app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');
window.Vue = require('vue');
import router from './router';
new Vue({
    el: "#app",
    router,
    // render: h => h(app)
});
```

router/index.js

```
import contestantComponent from '../components/Contestant/Contestant'
import contestantEditComponent from '../components/Contestant/EditContestant'
Vue.use(Router)
export default new Router({
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/contestant/:id',
            component: contestantComponent,
            children: [
                {

                    name: 'Contestant edit',
                    component: contestantEditComponent,
                    path: '/contestant/:id?/edit',
                },
                {
                    name: 'View contestant',
                    component: ViewContestantComponent,
                    path: '',
                }
            ],
    ]
})
```

When I add something to the input I get an error:

```
found in

---> <EditContestant> at resources/js/components/Contestant/EditContestant.vue
       <Contestant> at resources/js/components/Contestant/Contestant.vue
         <Root>
warn @ app.js:41366
logError @ app.js:42625
globalHandleError @ app.js:42620
handleError @ app.js:42580
invokeWithErrorHandling @ app.js:42603
invoker @ app.js:42916
original._wrapper @ app.js:48273
```

and

```
app.js:42629 TypeError: Cannot read property '$parent' of null
    at _c.on.input (app.js:37434)
    at invokeWithErrorHandling (app.js:42595)
    at HTMLInputElement.invoker (app.js:42916)
    at HTMLInputElement.original._wrapper (app.js:48273)
```

Comment: You don't need `this.` in template, just use `$parent`. Besides that, always try to use props & event instead of directly call the function thru `this.$parent.function()`. You should `$emit('callFunc')` then `@callFunc="function"`. Can you try to simulate it in JsBin?

Comment: @CloudSohJunFu I'll try to throw it online. How come this.$parent... does work? I mean it's populating my form with an actual, correct data? :|
EDIT:
Oh man/woman!! I love you! removing this worked. Thanks for the further tips. Would you be so kind and explain a bit more about where to use $emit in my use case? There is ton of examples, but all in single file mode. Vue.js allows too much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `this.` in template, just use `$parent`. Template is already in the `this.` scope.

The communication between parent and child should be using [**Props down events up**](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/style-guide/#Implicit-parent-child-communication-use-with-caution), instead of directly call the function thru `this.$parent.function()`. You should `$emit('callFunc')` then `@callFunc="function"`.

Answer (score 0):

removing `this` from `this.$parent...` in EditContestatn.vue file helped. Thank you for your help @CloudSohJunFu. If you wish to answer to my question I will gladly accept your answer and delete my own.

Comment: I have answered the question, any further question?