# Call a parent of parent function from child component

Tags: vue.js

I have a simpleMethod function in ChildComponent which calls a function of the parent component, but I have the next situation:

a ViewComponent extends a LayoutComponent and, inside the Child Component. Something like this:

ChildComponent:

```
<template>
  <button @click="simpleMethod">smth</button>
</template>
<script>
...
methods: {
  simpleMethod() {
    this.$parent.parentFunction()
  }
}
</script>
```

ViewComponent:

```
<template>
  <onepage-layout>
    <child-component></child-component>
  </onepage-layout>
</template>
<script>
...
methods: {
  parentFunction() {
    console.log('I want to fire this function...')
  }
}
</script>
```

So, when child component fires simpleMethod function, it search the function in OnePageLayout component instead ViewComponent.

I think that I could create a parentFunction inside OnePageLayout just like the one in child component, but I imagine that it's not efficient or a good practice.

Any idea?

Comment: The way that a child component typically interacts with parent components is through events. I can't elaborate much at the moment, but your view component should listen for an event that is fired by the child and call the parentFunction in response.

Comment: @obermillerk i've try with $emit from child and listen it from the ViewComponent and it works!, thank you

Answer (score 2):

Child Component:

```
<template>
  <button @click="simpleMethod">smth</button>
</template>
<script>
...
methods: {
  simpleMethod() {
    this.$emit('callParentFunction'); // emit an event to parent
  }
}
</script>
```

ViewComponent:

```
<template>
  <onepage-layout>
    <child-component @callParentFunction="parentFunction"></child-component>
  </onepage-layout>
</template>
<script>
...
methods: {
  parentFunction() {
    console.log('I want to fire this function...')
  }
}
</script>
```

You can refer to my another [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55552137/8703393).

> The communication between parent and child should be using Props down events up, instead of directly call the function thru `this.$parent.function()`. You should `$emit('callFunc')` then `@callFunc="function"`.

Answer (score 1):

A good way to accomplish this is using a new vue instance as event bus :

window.EventBus = new Vue();

In your child component you can run `childFunction`:

```
 methods: {

        childFunction() {
            EventBus.$emit('call-parent-function')
        }

    }
```

Then in any component (like parent of parent!) you can listen to the event:

```
 created() {           

        EventBus.$on('call-parent-function', () => {
            this.parentFunction();
        })

    }
```

Comment: Thank you, it's better than just emit and listen the event in the component like the comment down below?